# Wordpress Page order

Tags: wordpress, menu

I can't get the page order to update in wordpress.

http://s72956.gridserver.com/dev/ that is the page but it should look like this http://i32.tinypic.com/5aa82.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem :I forgot to set the page order popup choice in the Pages sidebar widget. I'm using widgets so that's where I overlooked the change.